# Is it legit to use 'document' to name my variables?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I have a function

```
function processDocument (document) {
    if (document.name === "client-invoice") {
        // Do something with the document
    }
}
```

Where `document` is an object I get from some other place, so it's not a browser document, but just any object with the same name. I suspect that when I check for the `document.name` to equal to some value, it doesn't look into the passed parameter object, but into the browser document object.

If so, I will rename my variable to not conflict with the browser `document` object.

The question, is my assumption correct and should I avoid naming my variables `document`?

Comment: "I suspect that …" — That's trivial to test. Why not test it instead of asking Stackoverflow?

Comment: I have a large app I work in and I am not quite yet familiar with it, so I just want to make sure that there weren't a mistake of other developers with naming the variable like so or if it was done on purpose.

Comment: Large apps don't prevent you from writing small, stand-alone test cases.

Comment: I agree, but knowing some unobvious JS quirks I could suppose it was done on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> is my assumption correct

No

```js
var document_copy = document;

function myFunction(document) {
    alert("Locally scoped document === global document_copy: " + (document_copy === document));  
}

myFunction("some value");
```

> and should I avoid naming my variables document?

Yes. It's a name that is likely to confuse people who have to maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

No, It will work.

But I can recommend you to avoid using `document` named variable in your code. It can confuse in future.

```js
function processDocument (document) {
  
  alert(document);
  
  if (document.name === "client-invoice") {

    return ''
  }
}

processDocument('Test')
```